# Copy one file to many files without invoking cp too many times

Tags: bash, copy

```
touch source
$ echo dest.{000000..999999} | tr ' ' '\n' | while read dest ; do echo cp -v source $dest ; done
cp -v source dest.000000
cp -v source dest.000001
cp -v source dest.000002
cp -v source dest.000003
cp -v source dest.000004
cp -v source dest.000005
cp -v source dest.000006
cp -v source dest.000007
cp -v source dest.000008
cp -v source dest.000009
...
```

Well, this is gonna take forever, mainly because each copy invokes a new `cp` process.

Let's try with xargs:

```
$ echo dest.{000000..999999} | xargs -n 1000 cp source
cp: target 'dest.000999' is not a directory
```

Yeah, right, when giving multiple arguments, `cp` assumes that `n-1` arguments are source files, and the `nth` argument is a destination directory.

I need a command that works differently:

```
mycp source dest1 dest2 dest3 ...
```

How could I achieve this, without invoking a new process for each copy?

Comment: @Cyrus this is also a page for bash programmers, who make use of readily available tools without having to reinvent the wheel every tuesday morning. Is the wheel already invented for this particular case?

Comment: @Cyrus, not real,y that would still call one process per entry. I have a solution which I am going to post below

Comment: @Cyrus why faster? One process still needs to be run for each file

Answer (score 0):

(based on the suggestion by Cyrus)

This works:

```
function multi-cp () {
  local source="$1"
  shift
  tee "${@}" < "$source" > /dev/null
}

echo dest.{000000..999999} | xargs -n 1000 | while read -r destinations ; do
    multi-cp source $destinations
done
```

We use `while` because `xargs` can not call functions (there are ways around this, but they have other problems). We still use `xargs` to split the arguments in manageable chunks.

This assumes that the arguments have no spaces (which is the case, since we are in control).